# "an NLP" or "a NLP"; which one is correct in written English?

Tags: articles

Which one is the correct form in written English? 
I am leaning towards "an NLP", since "N" starts with "e" but not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice between *a* and *an* always depends purely on the pronunciation of the following word, not on anything else. Hence *a universal understanding*. It doesn't depend on the *spelling* of the following word, which begins with a *u*, nor does it depend on the head noun *understanding*.

If you expect your readers to say "en el pee", then Yes, *an* is appropriate.